# When creating Vue instance how can I inject configuration and make it accessible in all components?

Tags: vuejs2

When creating Vue2 instance, how can I inject configuration and make it accessible to child component (except assigning it to window object)?

```
const config = axios.get('./run-configuration.json')

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '<App/>',
  components: {
    App
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach it to the Vue's prototype as:

```
Vue.prototype.$config = axios.get('./run-configuration.json')
```

Now it it will be available in al l the confinements and can be accessed using `this.$config`

Comment: This does not seems to work for me. axios.get() returns promise so, when accessing config I have to call it either as await in async function or deal with callback. 

Ofc, I can extend Vue prototype in successful callback of axios but meanwhile I might be creating Vue components without config (the prop $config wont be there until I resolve the promise).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $emit method to send your event to vue after the axios call is completed.

```
const config = axios.get('./run-configuration.json')
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '<App/>',
  components: {
    App
  },
  data: {
    config: {}
  },
  mounted: function(){
    config.then(cfg=>{
      //Set config in for this vue instance (scope)
      this.config = cfg;

      //Emit so that other components can listen and get the loaded value
      this.$emit("config-loaded", this.config);
    });
  }
});
```